# Is it possible to upload photos through a webapp in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

Is it possible to upload photos without creating a native app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nope there is no way you could do that. apple is not allowing that to happen

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/downloads/list (via [A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app))