# iPhone File Upload with HTML

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

Is there **any** way to use `<input type="file">` in Safari on iPhone/iPod Touch? Or is there something similar that I can use inside the browser? I want to upload a photo from the device to my database using the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app

Comment: Yes there is, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40529202/813988).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't be done with plain XHTML/javascript as Safari does not support uploads. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app) for a potential [workaround solution to upload photos](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/).

Comment: Honourable mention to http://picupapp.com which performs a similar function to the Google code, and is already deployed to the app store.

Comment: Now, in iOS 8 Safari mobile supports image upload

Comment: Safari on iOS6.0+ supports image/video upload & capture through `<input>`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40529202/813988)

Answer (score 19):

This is possible with iOs 6 or greater (http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#safari). The browser renders

```
<input type="file">
```

and clicking on "Choose File" prompts the user to take a new photo or choose existing from the photo library.

Comment: This method is very buggy, as you should use `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />` instead. See [Andy's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784352/iphone-file-upload-with-html#answer-19576153).

Comment: How to do it for audio files? `accept="audio/*"` doesn't work.

Comment: Audio is part of the spec (http://w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#attr-input-accept) but it is up to the browser to support it or not and currently safari for ios does not. Found this table for browser support (a bit old) http://books.google.com.au/books?id=gswdarRZVUoC&lpg=PA263&dq=file%20upload%20compatibility%20table&pg=PA263#v=onepage&q=file%20upload%20compatibility%20table&f=false

Comment: Can we able to upload pdf document ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. The alternative browser [iCab Mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8) does support file uploads. I got it for my iPad and (at least for me) file upload works fine.