# File upload fails in iOS 11 in AngularJS webapp

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, iphone, file-upload

I have created a webapp meant for both desktop and mobile devices, using Angular JS. There's one page with the feature to upload a file to the server. File upload button is created using:

```
 <input type="file" auto-upload="addFile"/>`
```

The file upload button works perfectly fine on desktop, Android devices and iPhone (iOS 10.x.x) but fails on iPhones with iOS 11.x.x
It doesn't even open a dialog to select a file regardless of the browser you use. The button click doesn't nothing.

Does anyone have any clue to what's happening here?

---

## auto-upload is a custom directive. Code is below:

```
directive('autoUpload', function () { 
   return { restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: { autoUpload: '=', 
                     jobSiq: '=' }, 
            link: function link($scope, element) {
                element.bind('change', function (e) {
                    $scope.autoUpload(e, $scope.jobSiq);
                    e.target.value = null;
                });
            } 
   }; 
})
```

Comment: See [Angular/Material Issue #1545 -- Input type="file" not working on mobile devices.](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1545).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone File Upload with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784352/iphone-file-upload-with-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app/40529202#40529202).

Comment: @georgeawg: auto-upload is a custom directive. Code is below:
`directive('autoUpload', function () {
  return {
   restrict: 'AEC',
   scope: {
    autoUpload: '=',
    jobSiq: '='
   },
   link: function link($scope, element) {
    element.bind('change', function (e) {
     $scope.autoUpload(e, $scope.jobSiq);
     e.target.value = null;
    });
   }
  };
 }`

Corrected the title now. It's iOS 11 and not 10. I'll look at the links you pointed to for further answers. Thanks a lot.