# SwfUpload flash uploader not visible and not working in IOS 

Tags: ios, flash, html, javax.script

i am working on a web application based on media gallery.In this application i am uploading media using SWFUpload either images and videos.When i try to open my application on IOS then uploader not visible there.Where it is working fine on safari installed on windows.I want some suggestions from experts of this field.
one site who is using SWFUpload is http://www.ehproductions.com/mediaimage.htm.
Here SwfUploader working nice on windows but not on IOS machines.

Is there any javax html5 compatible uploader?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the description of the SWFUpload:

> SWFUpload Upload files to a server via flash and listen all the events
>   from JavaScript.

As all we know there is no flash on the iOS devices, and as result ­— `uploader not visible there`. But the problem is not only in the flash. iOS misses html file input, so you cannot use the same tools you use with other OS/browser. Take a look at this question - ["A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app), — for possible workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @igor milla for this important information but is there any solution which come with Jquery here ?

Comment: sometimes even jQuery powerless