# Can I facillitate "uploads" in Mobile Safari with cloud API's?

Tags: html, mobile, safari

This is, perhaps, a rehash of an older SO question "[A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app)".   I realize that iOS Safari simply does not permit file uploads. However,  I was wondering if there are ways to leverage cloud storage API's such as Dropbox or iCloud so as to accomplish the same goal.    So,  for example, instead of a file upload dialog  I would have a url that links to dropbox/icloud that could then prompt the user for the file to send.

Sorry if I'm being too vague - but I suppose I don't care too much about the mechanism of delivery.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the url belongs to a dropbox/icloud file then you don't even need to "select" any file since the url points to one already, so a simple textbox in a form should suffice.

If this is not what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for a  workflow similar to a payment processor e.g. paypal, but for files instead of money.  (here's a good visualization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513658/paypal-as-payment-option-workflow).   Allowing for a public icloud/dropbox url is a good idea (thanks!),  but it would be nice if there was a more "guided" process that would allow the user to navigate his/her (remote/cloud-based) file structure and choose the specific file(s).       Am I making any sense? If so, is there anything like that out there?