# Best way to support users sending profile pictures from mobile devices in a rails 3.0 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mobile-safari, carrierwave

We are using carrierwave in a Rails 3 app and it works great! However, on our mobile site the button to select a file is grayed out. I've read that an iPhone will not grant access to files from a browser. Is [Picup](http://picupapp.com/) my only option for iPhone? It would be great if there was a solution that worked for Android and other devices as well.

UPDATE:

I realize that many (most?) mobile devices do not give access to files. Trying to find the most effective way to email images.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone doesn't support uploading files from Mobile Safari.

Check [A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891831) for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I know. I am currently working on a solution to email profile pics.