# Upload file from iPhone media library, in 2012

Tags: ios, upload, media-library

I'm about to launch a service where one of the feature is to upload files with an 'upload' button on a website. Some years ago, I made some program for iPhone, and I remember that it was impossible to upload an MP3 from the library, because each app is in its sandbox, though I was able to upload MP3 placed in the sandbox itself.

There is an old post on SO about the impossibility to upload from the library to a website:

[A html5 web app for mobile safari to upload images from the Photos.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app)

Is possible as of may 2012 for an iPhone/iPad to be prompted into the music library when clicking on an html upload button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apple will not allow you to do this.**  Although it may be possible using private APIs or perhaps the Media Player framework, it will not be accepted by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think things will evolve in your way on iPhone.

I assume your service will not be in native objective-c. 
look at the features of phonegap to see what interactions are currently possible : 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/index.html

You can probably develop a dedicated app to extract the music file using the Media Player framework and send them to your service, but I barely doubt it can pass the apple verification team.