# How to allow users to upload images to our site via iOS browser?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, upload

Our site allows web users to upload images to their WordPress/BuddyPress profile and posts.  We have a responsive design, but iOS will not allow users to upload images when posting from their iphone. We don't want to have to build an entire app for this - any suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app -- in particular, the person answering that question suggests that iOS 6 will allow users to upload images from their Photo Library in Safari, so once the new version is released, your users need only upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, by using a free app. 
See this:
http://buddypress.org/community/groups/how-to-and-troubleshooting/forum/topic/users-cant-upload-their-avatar-when-on-mac/

Answer (score -2):

Suggest users use a different browser like iCab. [iCab at the App Store.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8)