# How to manually install Phonegap libraries without Xcode?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

Do I need to install Phonegap libraries or is it enough to copy them to a place where the app scripts stay?

I am developing an app in javascript,html,jquery,css php ect using Dreamweaver on Windows. I want to use cordova-2.0.0 which is the last version of Phonegap for uploading pictures from an album or from capturing them. I have grabbed the full example from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera This code requires src="cordova-2.0.0.js" and the problem is I do not know if I should install Phonegap or copy its libraries to a place that the sample script can see them.

Answer (score 0):

You copy the PhoneGap libraries to a suitable location and then you import the files into your application project. [PhoneGap homepage](http://phonegap.com/) provide details on how to do this.

Since you don't want to use Xcode, I'm assuming it is because you are using Windows. Have you seen this guide about creating Phonegap iOS apps?

[Detailed Guide for setting up building iOS apps without a Mac](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac)

**EDIT:** If you are trying to create a web app that is accessed from Safari, and you are trying to upload photos, then you should probably read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app)

Comment: Thnx I have added more details to the question.I have almost finished the app using Dreamweaver just want to exploit camera library.

Comment: are you distributing via App Store, or is it a web app accessed through safari?

Comment: right now is a web app later will distribute via App store .What is the difference?

Comment: PhoneGap is for "wrapping" a web app into an ordinary app so that you can distribute in on the App Store. If you are accessing the app via Safari then neither you can or need to use PhoneGap. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Phonegap also provides libraries like for instance for capturing photos via camera and that is why I need to use it.Do you know any other option for implementing this functionality (capturing pictures).

Comment: I have grabbed the full phonegap example from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera ,but if you know any other libaray please tell me?

Comment: See my updated answer. Yes you are right that PhoneGap provides such functions, but that doesn't mean that you can use PhoneGap via Safari, you still have to make a real app and not a web app.
To upload pictures through safari, you need to use iOS6 (see linked question in my answer)

Comment: No there is no such library, there is no way to access photos and upload things via safari up to iOS5. In iOS6 Safari will support those functions, but then your users need to have iOS6 on their phones.

Comment: ok thank you very much but could you please provide me with the full link of PhoneGap page with guidelines on coping PhoneGap libraries to a suitable location and then...

Comment: on the guide there are given the steps one have to follow on Mac while I need for windows

Comment: There is no such instructions on the PhoneGap page, that is why I linked you the guide above "Detailed Guide for setting up building iOS apps without a Mac". However note that you have to make a real app, you can't do what you are requesting in a web app. PhoneGap require to be installed on every users phone via an app that you provide on AppStore, do you understand? You can't simply import in your web page...

Comment: ok it makes me clear .but how to test it during the development process?

Comment: Make an iPhone app =) you can test it using emulator for free (requires xcode) or on device if you register as an iPhone developer: https://developer.apple.com/programs/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it without xcode so maybe not the best answer however you could try IBM Worklight which is an eclipse based IDE that has PhoneGap or alternatively would be to look at something like Sencha Touch which has native development capabilities in HTML5 as well.